# Mongos error : Unable to connect to mongodb atlas sandbox

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently learning mongodb-mongoose-express and nodejs using the [local-library tutorial from MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose)

As instructed, i created a sandbox db in Mongodb-atlas.During the schema creation step, i am provided with a populatedb.js, which would facilitate the population of data into mongodb.

However i am stuck while connecting to this sandbox db, there is a connection error. I have tried numerous times, however, i could not connect.

Connection string:

> mongodb://admin:admin@locallibrary-shard-00-00-h9ahx.mongodb.net:27017,locallibrary-shard-00-01-h9ahx.mongodb.net:27017,locallibrary-shard-00-02-h9ahx.mongodb.net:27017/locallibrary?ssl=true&replicaSet=locallibrary-shard-0&authSource=admin

I am attaching the screenshot of the error that i received in the command prompt. Can anyone help on this.

[image: Connection error]

Comment: Which mongoose version are you using ?

Comment: Which nodejs version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DNS Seedlist Connection Format for your URI, see [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@bc0-xcdi0.mongodb.net/
```

In the Mongoose connect function you'll need to add the database name as an option because of this bug: [Make DNS Seedlist Connection Format compatible with 3.6.1](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1286)

```
mongoose.connect('YOUR-DB-URI', { dbName: 'YOUR-DB-NAME' });
```